# MySQL SELECT statement won't accept two php variables

Tags: php, mysql, database, variables, select

```
<?php
    function searchDatabase($key, $value)
    {
        $key = $key;
        $query = "SELECT * FROM user_data WHERE username='$value'";
        $result = mysqli_query(loadDatabase(), $query);
        $numRows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        if ($numRows > 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
?>
```

So I am using this code to search through my database to reveal a match on a *key/value* pair, but `$key` doesn't find the correct column in my database when passed into the query function. If I replace it with the word username, it matches fine. Is it a type issue? I am not explicitly stating its type so I can search other columns with the same function.

`username: varchar(40)`

Comment: Uh? `$key = $key;` must be a mistake? replace `username` by `$key`.

Comment: `$query = "SELECT * FROM user_data WHERE username='$value'";`
 should be `$query = "SELECT * FROM user_data WHERE username='".$value."'";`

Comment: Your code is vulnerable. Don't use mysqli without real-escape-string, because your site will attackable by SQL injection.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
function searchDatabase($key, $value)
    {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM user_data WHERE ".$key." = '".$value."'";
        $result = mysqli_query(loadDatabase(), $query);
        $numRows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        return ($numRows > 0);
    }
?>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked for me! So what exactly happened? Was it a type issue?

Comment: You used username instead $key.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM user_data WHERE ".$key."='$value'";
```

Answer (score 0):

Like so:

```
function searchDatabase($key, $value)
{
  $query = "SELECT * FROM user_data WHERE $key='$value'";
  $result = mysqli_query(loadDatabase(), $query);
  $numRows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
  return ($numRows > 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the query. PHP variables are not properly echoed in the query.

```
<?php
function searchDatabase($key, $value)
    {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM user_data WHERE username='".$value."'";
        $result = mysqli_query(loadDatabase(), $query);
        $numRows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        return ($numRows > 0);
    }
?>
```